# MongoDB 3.4 how to convert string to date using a specific date format

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I have the following documents;

```
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b85312981c1634f59751604"),
  "date" : "0"
 },

 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b85312981c1634f59751604"),
  "date" : "20180330"
 },

 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b85312981c1634f59751604"),
  "date" : "20180402"
 },

 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b85312981c1634f59751604"),
  "date" : "20180323"
 },
```

I am using `MongoDB 3.4`, I want to convert `date` to `ISODate` using the format of `year-month-day`, and `0` will yield `1970-01-01`, so the result will look like,

```
"date" : ISODate("1970-01-01")
"date" : ISODate("2018-03-30")
"date" : ISODate("2018-04-02")
"date" : ISODate("2018-03-23")
```

Comment: can you update mongoDB 3.4 to mongoDB 3.6 or above so we can use aggregation to make require result.

Comment: To add to @AshokPatidar 's comment, MongoDB 3.6 has an aggregation operator called `$dateFromString` which does exactly what you want: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/. If it's not possible to upgrade, then you would need to do this in the application code.

Comment: Did you find an answer@daiyue?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use below [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

```
db.documents.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
      year: { $toString: { 
          $trunc: { $divide: [{ $toInt: '$date' }, 10000] } } 
      },
      month: {
        $toString: {
          $trunc: { $divide: [{ $mod: [{ $toInt: '$date' }, 10000] }, 100] }
        }
      },
      day: {
        $toString: {
          $trunc: { $mod: [{ $toInt: '$date' }, 100] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      date: {
        $toDate: {
          $cond: [
            { $ne: ['$year', '0'] }, 
            { $concat: ['$year', '-', '$month', '-', '$day'] },
            new Date("")
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If you have any idea to convert **date** "YYYYMMDD" string into **year**("YYYY"), **month**("MM"), **day**("DD") then we can make it more simple

Comment: thank you for your solution, I am wondering how to do it using `$dateFromString` operator?

Comment: {$project:{_id:0,date:{$dateFromString:{dateString:{$cond:[{$ne:['$year','0']},{$concat:['$year','-','$month','-','$day']},"1970-01-01"]}}}}} use it in last stage if you want to use `$dateFromString` operator. But you have to find year, month, day from "YYYYMMDD"

Comment: Unrecognized expression '$toString', it only exists in MongoDB 4.0+

Comment: $toDate is in MongoDB 4.0, this question was for 3.4

Comment: @AsifSaeed yes [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) and [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) both are from Mongodb ^4.0.  Apology for inconvenience caused.